# Asking Questions About Advantages and Disadvantages

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

On Unix-StackExchange, can I ask questions like "When configuring the Linux kernel, what are the advantages and disadvantages of enabling UTS namespaces?"? (This is a real question that I want to ask.)

Also, if I were to ask the above question, can I ask similar, but yet different questions like "What are the advantages and disadvantages of disabling IPC namespaces in the Linux kernel?"? (Another real question that I have).

Comment: I'd say go ahead and ask them. It will be an issue only when you seem to spam the site with *too many* such questions, in a short period of time. It's subjective what *too many* is, so just go ahead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little reluctant to disagree with the answers already posted by highly rated users, but I'll toss in a word of caution:   Do your research first.   If you have a whole series of these questions, I think it seems like you should start by finding a good guide to kernel configs/options (there are quite a few).

Alternately, try and come up with a more focused question.   I don't know if this makes sense in this specific case, but maybe something like "I'm trying to set up a system to do __.   Do IPC and UTS conflict?"   Or something else fairly specific.   IOW, while one or two of these might be OK, SE isn't a primary source for research - if you're looking to learn about a topic and don't have a specific question, do some reading.

Sounds like you're already thinking about this (or you wouldn't have asked), so just a vote for 'good concern, use some caution'.

Answer (score 7):

If the question is specific enough, I'd say go for it; those look like they probably have a short list of concrete reasons. It'd be nice if you didn't post 30 of them at once, and avoid things like "What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Linux?" where there are infinite possible answers